# How do I drop a table column in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wish to drop a table column in SQL Server 2012, without affecting other columns in the table (and their data).

How can I do this? Is it possible at all?

So far I've tried deleting the column via SQL Server Management Studio, but this says the whole table must be dropped and re-created.

Comment: [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: Why should it be closed? The answer may be simple, but does it mean the question doesn't make sense? It's not that trivial, considering SQL Server Management Studio refused to do it.

Comment: You **are** aware that Microsoft publishes an **extensive** online documentation called [**SQL Server Books Online**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) on their MSDN site - right?? It's there for everyone to consult, and it's totally absolutely **FREE** of charge

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175491.aspx)

`ALTER TABLE dbo.Table DROP COLUMN column_b`

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. Wondering why Management Studio refused to do the same thing.

Comment: @aknuds1: did you run into a message something like *not allowed since this operation would require table recreation*? That's an option in SSMS - [see this screenshot here on how to turn it off](http://i50.tinypic.com/qqdgna.png) (that's under `Tools > Options`)

Comment: @marc_s That looks about right. Does this imply SSMS would drop the table and re-create it though? Dropping the column in SQL didn't have any such ramifications, as the remaining columns and their data weren't affected.

Comment: @aknuds1: yes, the Visual Designer in SSMS does a lot of operations by just re-creating the table and copying around the data - even though the actual T-SQL wouldn't really requires this

Comment: @marc_s Is this to say the data would be restored upon table re-creation?

Comment: @aknuds1: yes - SSMS would (1) rename the existing table to a temporary name, (2) create the new table with the desired layout, and (3) copy back the data from all non-dropped columns

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN column_name
```

Answer (score 1):

To drop column

```
alter table tblname drop column colname
```

To add column

```
alter table tblname add colname datatype
```